# Variable access in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

why i cant access to variable "rows" in method parse?
If i put  this.setState({rows: [3,2]});  outside of "parseString it works, but what to do to make it work inside this method?

```
 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getCleanState();
    this.parse = this.parse.bind(this);
 }


 getCleanState() {

    return {

        isLoading: true,
        columns:[
            { name: 'a:ClientID', title: 'ID kombinace'},
            { name: 'a:Name', title: 'Název kombinace'},
        ],
        defaultColumnWidths: [
            { columnName: 'a:ClientID', width: 160 },
            { columnName: 'a:Name', width: 200 },

          ],
        rows:[],
        selection: [],


    };
} 

 parse(XML){
        var parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;
        var xml = XML;
        parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
        this.setState({rows: [3,2]});
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you use an anonymous function that is not binded.

Use arrow function for instance (or explicitly bind)

```
parse(XML){
    var parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;
    var xml = XML;
    parseString(xml, (err, result) => {
        console.dir(result);
        this.setState({rows: [3,2]});
    });
}
```